# Robot test fails when run on Circle CI

Tags: robotframework, circleci

when I run my Robot test locally all is fine. I have a very basic Scala Play project with a couple of html pages. This project uses bitbucket, is built using Circle Ci and uses a Docker image. My **Dockerfile** looks like this...

```
FROM circleci/python:2.7-stretch-browsers

USER root

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade robotframework robotframework-httplibrary robotframework-seleniumlibrary requests robotframework-requests python-jose robotframework-jsonlibrary naked
```

This is my .robot file...

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  This is some basic info about the whole suite
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***
User must login to visit landing page
    [Documentation]  This is some basic information about the test
    [Tags]  Smoke
    Open Browser  http://localhost:9000  headlesschrome
    #Open Browser  http://localhost:9000  chrome
    Wait Until Page Contains  The Login and Authentication App!
    Sleep  2s
    Click Link  Continue
    Wait Until Page Contains  User Login
    Sleep  1s
    Input Text  username  geoff
    Sleep  1s
    Input Text  password  123
    Sleep  2s
    Click Button  Login
    Sleep  2s
    Wait Until Page Contains  Landing Page!
    Sleep  2s
    Click Link  logout
    Wait Until Page Contains  You are logged out.
    Sleep  2s
    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
```

There are 2 steps at the circle ci end. **Build** (includes 3 unit tests) and **run robot test**. The build is fine but the Robot tests are failing. This is the output from Circlci...

```
==============================================================================
User must login to visit landing page :: This is some basic inform... .User must login to visit landing page :: This is some basic inform... | FAIL |
Text 'The Login and Authentication App!' did not appear in 5 seconds.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Amazon :: This is some basic info about the whole suite               | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /root/project/output.xml
Log:     /root/project/log.html
Report:  /root/project/report.html
Exited with code 1
```

I suspect there is some issue with CircleCi and headlesschrome. I have tried using a different Docker image that installs a lot of Chrome stuff but to be fair that felt like a stab in the dark. Any ideas about how I can fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: The failure is past the `Open Browser keyword`, so apparently that succeeds, not an issue starting the headless chrome. To debug further, you could do something different - get/log the opened page's source, and see localhost:9000 is serving the same thing on the CI environment, as the one you expect. Use the keyword `Log Source` for that.

Comment: @Todor thanks for the reply. Will try that. The person who down voted my question. Seriously how would you know what effort or research I have put into solving this? If you're not clear about the question as you say, go and do something else.

Comment: There's no point of starting a rhetoric with anonymous downvoters, it seldom ends well :) Here's an upvote to neutralize, the question is well structured and interesting enough.